# sidebar menu in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and was trying to make a Sidebar like menu in my Application. I want to load appropriate windows in the right side (75% of the total width) based on the items selected in the sidebar (located in the left, 25% of the total width). Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but that's not much of a question!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can have Window inside another Window that is one of the difference between UserControl and Window that you cant have Window as child of another Window but you can have one or more UserControls as child.But you can do that using Two Windows one for your Menu and another Window that is going to be according to your selected Item in Menu. But you must set the SideBar Windows **TopMost** property True.I hope this will give you an idea

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Will the Frame control help me in this?

Comment: I had used Window Control for both

Comment: I had made application with this same feature and I had used Window.So cant say anything about Frame because I never used this Control.

Comment: I can't find a control called Window. Am I missing something?